# I want to show some payment method option if grand total amount greater than 3000 in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

Need to show one checkbox in product details page and if customer choose these checkbox then need to show only one payment method option in checkout page.
Condition is:
if grand total amount greater than 3000 and customer choose checkbox.Is it possible in magento?

Answer (score 1):

Create a module with an observer on "payment_method_is_active" event.

You should then check if this is the payment method you want

```
$MethodInstance    = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
$paymentMethodCode = $MethodInstance->getCode();

if ($paymentMethodCode == 'cashondelivery') {
    ...
}
```

Get the total from the quote,

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
```

Set the isAvailable flag on the payment method you with to limit.

```
$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

if ($result->isAvailable) {
    $result->isAvailable = $this->isTotalOverThreshold();
}
```

Here's a similar module I wrote for filtering payment methods by shipping country.

https://github.com/peacockcarter/magento-filter-payment-methods-on-shipping-address

This is actually a very good idea for a module. Might write it later in the week.

Comment: Thanks.I already implement.My logic is: 1)First i create custom option checkbox(name is "Avail EMI Offer") from manage product->my product->custom option. 2) Then copy this custom attribute for all products which products price greater or equal 3000. 3) If customer check this checkbox when he/she add to cart. 4) In checkout page, I receive this custom option in a variable and implement logic if variable=='1' then only show EMI payment method else show  cash on delivery payment method.

Comment: But i need to implement custom option pragmatically. Is it possible ? I am Beginner

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is , for your condition better set the checkbox in checkout page instead of product detail page. Just check for the Grand total from the quote on the checkout page , if Grand total > 3000 makes the check box to be visible else let the checkbox be hidden

Comment: Thanks.I already implement this logic.But i need to add  checkbox in product details page pragmatically.